# PHP & MYSQL - How To Check If Two Or More Rows Have The Same Field Value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So here's the problem I can't work around today.

I want to grab some details from a database. I'm not sure how to explain this. But here goes.

Database Example:

### TITLE | DESCRIPTION | IDENTIFIER

1     |  Description  | abc
2     |  Description  | abc
3      | Description  | def

I want to select the first row with the identifier "abc" and then I want to skip the next row which has the same field "abc".

I'm trying to use this in a SELECT mysql_query in PHP

Comment: `group by identifier`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the integer field is called 'title'.  This should grab the lowest title # but remove the duplicates as you requested.

```
select min(title) as firstTitle, description, identifier
  from table_name
  where identifier in (select distinct identifier from table_name)
  group by description, identifier.
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the complete row you can do

```
select * from your_table
where title in 
(
  select min(title)
  from your_table
  group by identifier
)
```

Comment: Will this not always return true as you're not stopping it from matching itself in that subselect?

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(identifier), title, description FROM tablename
```

It will also return the row with 'def' in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(TITLE) as TITLE, DESCRIPTION , IDENTIFIER 
From your_table
Group by DESCRIPTION , IDENTIFIER
```

Comment: I used the title numbers an example. Sorry for the confusion !

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, description, identifier 
from table group by identifier order by id asc;
```